# "flutter doctor" command just returns "'flutter' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Tags: flutter

I am trying to start learning flutter, but I can't get it to work. I have downloaded the file, extracted all files to my C drive, I added it to my path, but when I put "flutter doctor" into the flutter console it says "'flutter' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.". Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this and get it working?

Comment: Where is your Flutter SDK and environment path?

Answer (score 2):

Add path/to/flutter/bin in environment variables and try.

Answer (score 0):

if you change the path in the 'Environmental Variables for your account' to flutter/bin, I'm sure it is going to work

Comment: You should *add* flutter to your path, your computer might behave is various strange ways if you replace your entire path with only flutter